# Constructor of Nested Classes of Templates Classes in C++

Tags: c++, class, templates, constructor, nested

I have a nested class inside a template class and wish to implement its constructor outside of the scope.
However, I get the following error:

> expected unqualified-id before ')' token

```
template<class T>
class mainClass {
private:
    class nestedClass {
    public:
        nestedClass();
    };
};

template<class T>
typename mainClass<T>::nestedClass::nestedClass(){
    // code here
}
```

Comment: Remove the `typename`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `typename`:

```
template<class T>
mainClass<T>::nestedClass::nestedClass(){
    // code here
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e3f08e9c3a7e4734)

For more info on in which contexts we need to use `typename` see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/613132/2352671).

Comment: It doesn't work.
I think it must have a typename for the compiler to realize that nestedClass is a type and not something else (e.g. a static variable or a function).

Answer (score 0):

It seems my problem concerned another bug which I had not noticed up until now.
In any regard, it is true that `typename` was not required in the context in which it was used.

Thank you.